# Eclipselink merge fails to generate UPDATE statement for changed value

Tags: java, jpa, orm, eclipselink

I have 2 objects joined together defined as such:

```
public class A {
    ...
    @Id
    @Column(name = "A_ID")
    @SequenceGenerator(...)
    @GeneratedValue(...)
    public Long getA_ID();

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "a", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity = B.class)
    public B getB();
    ...
}

@VirtualAccessMethods(get = "getMethod", set = "setMethod")
public class B {
    ...

    @Id
    public Long getA_ID();

    @MapsId
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL ,targetEntity = A.class)
    @JoinColumn(name="A_ID")
    public A getA();

    getMethod(String name);

    setMethod(String name, Object value);
    ...
}
```

When I go to `em.merge(A)` with B joined onto A for an `INSERT`, everything works fine.  However if I do the same thing for an update, it will update only A.  The update logic is like so:

```
@Transactional
public void update(Object fieldOnANewValue, Object fieldOnBNewField) {
    A objA = em.executeQuery(...) //loads objA by primary key
    objA.setFieldOnA(fieldOnANewValue);
    B objB = objA.getB(); //lazy loads objB
    objB.setMethod("FieldOnB", fieldOnBNewValue);
}
```

If I look at the logs, there is a SQL `UPDATE` statement committing the changes I made to A, but nothing for B.  If I manually call `em.merge(objB)` the same issue exists.  Does anyone know exactly what EclipseLink does to determine whether or not to generate an `UPDATE` statement?  Particularly with regard to `@VirtualAccessMethods`?  However, I have had the @OneToOne mappings setup differently before and `em.merge(objB)` worked fine then, plus `INSERT` works, so I'm not sure if that's the issue.  On the flip side, if I have another object that is also joined onto A, but just is a normal POJO like A is, the `UPDATE` statement is generated for that.  Caching is turned off, and I've verified that the objects are updated correctly before merge is called.

Comment: The merge operation should not even be necessary, since A and B are attached. Any change made to them should be transparently written to the database at flush time. merge must be used to merge a *detached* entity state to an *attached* one. Merging an already attached instance is unnecessary.

Comment: Removing the `em.merge()` calls results in the same issue of an `UPDATE` for A being generated, but not for B.

Comment: The problem must be behind `//copy updatedInfoA into objA`. Show us this code.

Comment: I assume you mean for B.  All I do is call setMethod() with the updated value.  setMethod() just overrides the value in a map.  What I don't know is how EclipseLink determines for these virtual methods when a field gets updated.  In the map, the field is clearly updated, but EclipseLink isn't picking up on this. 

Based on what you told me, the reason this must have worked before was because we had to make new entities due to the joins being readonly, and then when we called merge it would pickup the changes.

Comment: No, I meant for A. If all it does is update a value in a Map, then I don'tsee why B would be modified, since the Map is, I guess, used to hold an association to another entity. Without seeing any concrete code, we can only guess what's wrong. If you want some help, show us the code.

Comment: I can't show you the actual code because I work for a company.  I updated the question to reflect essentially all I'm doing.  I understand this makes it more difficult to pinpoint the actual problem, but there's nothing I can do about that, which is really why I'm asking how does EclipseLink determine whether or not to generate an `UPDATE` statement, which seems to be, how does it know whether or not a field gets changed?

Comment: Sorry, but I also work for a company, so I'm afraid I won't be able to share anything with you. Find someone in your company that will have the right to look at your non-working trade secrets based on open-source software.

Comment: Thanks anyway JB, I appreciate the effort.  I'm sorry I couldn't share the actual code, but it's not my policy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please show the complete code and mappings.

Given you are using virtual access (are you using this correctly?), it could be some sort of change tracking issue related to the virtual access.  Does the issue occur without using virtual access?

Try setting,

@ChangeTracking(ChangeTrackingType.DEFERRED)

to see if this has an affect.

You could also try,

@InstantiationCopyPolicy

Comment: I don't know if the virtual access is being used correctly.  Due to the fact that if I add objects C and D, where C is a normal POJO and D is virtual access like B, C works but B and D don't, so I'm fairly certain the problem has to do with change tracking with regard to virtual access.  I'll try those suggestions now.

Comment: @ChangeTracking(ChangeTrackingType.DEFERRED) generated the update statements for the objects with virtual access.  Thank you very much James!